# Matching unequal columns in excel

Tags: database, excel, sorting

I have a list of people who have completed an intelligence test (names are stored in Column D) and another alphabetical list of people who have completed a second intelligence test (and their scores) in columns A and B respectively.

The list of people stored in column A is much bigger (N = 3000) than the list in column D (N = 800). I need to match Column A  (and their scores) to Column D, whilst keeping Column D in the order it is in.

I have tried various MATCH and VLOOKUP functions but they do not achieve what I would like. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: They do not achieve what you would like, how? It doesn't work? It's too slow? `VLOOKUP` sounds like the right way to go -- what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try a straight foward `VLOOKUP`?

```
=VLOOKUP(D2, A:B, 2, 0)
```

and drag down